# Work and its nature?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

Suppose we have a constant force $\overrightarrow{F}$ and in the direction of force we have 2 point $x_1$ and $x_2$ in that order. And we have to calculate work done on moving frok $x_1$ to $x_2$ and $x_2$ to $x_1$. Why and where is the following going wrong ?

1. Moving from $x_1$ to $x_2$

   > $$W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \overrightarrow{dx}$$
   >   $$W = F [dx]_{x_1}^{x_2}$$
   >   $$W = F (x_2 - x_1)$$
2. Moving from $x_2$ to $x_1$

   > $$W = \int_{x_2}^{x_1} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot (-\overrightarrow{dx})$$
   >   $-$ sign because $dx$ is in opposite direction as that of $F$
   >   $$W = \int_{x_2}^{x_1} -F dx$$
   >   $$W = -F [dx]_{x_2}^{x_1}$$
   >   $$W = -F (x_1 -x_2)$$
   >   $$W = F (x_2 - x_1)$$

Why is the work done in both cases coming out same?.

Comment: I don't think you have to take $-dx$. I've never used that/seen that done yet.

Comment: @mikhailcazi : do you mean to say you dont take dot product of force and displacement before integrating ?

Comment: I mean to say I've never worked with a *implicitly* negative differential. :)

Comment: At least, not in the case of physical work.

Comment: Well you **have** to take a negative sign when force and displacement are in opposite direction ! That's what I have done.

Comment: Is the force in both cases the same force in the same direction?

Comment: Yes indeed it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes in when you change the sign of $d\vec{x}$ to $-d\vec{x}$ in part 2.  The differential element $d\vec{x}$ always points in the direction from the lower bound of the integral ($x_2$ in this case) to the upper bound ($x_1$).  Since you switched the bounds of the integral in part 2, you already switch the direction.  By including a negative sign, you end up switching the direction again and thus have a integral equivalent to that of part 1).

---

Below is an explicity calculation done in regards to some sign confusion when calculating work.

Let us first consider the work done by gravity ($\vec{F}=-mg\hat{x}$) on an object moving from the point $\vec{x_1}=x_1\hat{x}$ to $\vec{x_2}=x_2\hat{x}$ where $x_2>x_1$.

This is $W_1 = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F (-\hat{x}) \cdot  (\hat{x}) dx = -F \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx = -F(x_2 - x_1)$

where $F=mg$

Thus we see $W_1$ is negative, which makes physical sense since the work done by gravity as the object moves up counteracts the motion of the object.

Now, let us consider the work done as the object moves down.

This is $W_2 = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F (-\hat{x}) \cdot  (-\hat{x}) dx = F \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx = F(x_2 - x_1)$

Note that here the differential element $d\vec{x}$ is now equal to $dx(-\hat{x})$ (i.e. it's pointing down).  Also note, that I could also flip my integral bounds such that they go from $x_2$ to $x_1$, but in this case the sign of the differential element would be negative and thus the direction of the differential element would be positive (i.e. $d\vec{x} = -dx(-\hat{x}) = dx\hat{x}$).

From this we see that $W_2$ is positive, again making physical sense since the work done by gravity is now in the direction of the object's motion.

Adding together $W_1$ and $W_2$ we see that the total work $W=W_1 + W_2$ done by gravity on the object is zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But can you just give a source ? A text or something I can refer my friends etc ? Also what about solving the dot product ? The negative sign in 2nd case is due to dot product !

Comment: I don't know of a specific resource off the top of my head, but I'm sure this can be found in any calculus book.  What we're doing here is switching the bounds of an integral and showing that that's equivalent to the original integral (without the bounds switched) multiplied by negative one.

Comment: But if I would not do dot product with $-dx$ that would be wrong as force and displacement are in opposite direction. I **HAVE** taken the displacement direction as you say and then dot product with force in case 1 give $Fdx$ while in case 2 give $-Fdx$ So where is it going wrong ?

Comment: The differential element $d\vec{x}$ always points along the path from the lower bound of the integral to the upper bound of the integral.

Comment: Agreed ! And that is why dot product is once positive and one negative !

Comment: Refer to my edit for details.

Comment: @rijulgupta: In your question you have mentioned about constant force. Constant force doesn't require integration.

Comment: @mcFreid: In second case, body moves from $x_2$ to $x_1$. So, you need to integrate from $x_2$ to $x_1$, which gives the same negative work according to your calculation.

Comment: @VINAY : I am aware that it is not required ! But I was checking where I was going wrong conceptually.

Comment: @rijulgupta: You have gone wrong in integration. You can look at my answer to see where you have gone wrong. I don't understand why mcFreid sir also has taken F as constant outside.

Comment: I understood that because of F being declared as constant in the question, mcFreid sir has taken F as constant.

Answer (score 2):

> The $dx$ is a signed quantity.

You don't need to put the negative sign explicitly.The infinitesimal displacement is always $dx \hat{i}$ and then $dW=\vec{F} \cdot dx \hat{i}=Fdx$.Whether the integral(work done) is positive or negative is decided by the limits.

Comment: You mean to say whether you are moving in $\hat{i}$ direction or $-\hat{i}$ direction, $dx$ is always in $\hat{i}$ direction ?

Comment: No,$dx \hat{i}$ can be in both directions.Remember,it is a signed quantity.So a negative value of $dx$ will imply a vector in the $-\hat{i}$ direction.

Comment: That **is** why I have put it there ! To signify the opposite direction of force and displacement which will ultimately give a negative sign after cross product.

Comment: You don't need to put the sign.The sign is "stored" in the $dx$.On the return journey,the infinitesimal work done is $Fdx$(all scalars) with $dx$ negative.So yes the work done is negative.If you use $F(-dx)$,$dx$ is already negative.The second negative sign now actually makes the work positive.

Comment: You haven't done dot product of $dx$ and $F$ ! The opposite directions will give inifinitesimal work done as $-Fdx$. Also after dot product we have absolute magnitude of $dx$ unlike a scalar which can be both positive and negative.

Comment: $F\cdot dx=Fdx$?(Again,$dx$ is a signed quantity).When the $F$ and $dx$ are opposite,$dx$ is negative and so is the dot product.

Comment: After dot product $F$ and $dx$ are positive only. $\overrightarrow{F}\cdot\overrightarrow{dx} = |\overrightarrow{F}||\overrightarrow{dx}|\cos\theta$ no signs are left after this !

Comment: And $|dx|=-dx$ since $dx$ is a negative quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Because in one case it is the work done by the force to move such object and the other is the work needed against the force applied to the object.

Comment: No it is not, see again !

Answer (score 1):

[In the present calculation variable force is considered instead of constant force, but the solution will not be altered, it remains same]
If a body is at rest at $x_1$ and the force $\overrightarrow{F}$ is applied on the body to displace it through $\overrightarrow{dx}$ along the direction of the force. Then, the small work done   in moving the body from $x_1$ to $x_2$ can be obtained by integrating the above between proper limits. Thus, total work done in moving the body from the point $x_1$ to $x_2$ is given by
$$W=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\overrightarrow{F}.\overrightarrow{dx}$$
As force acts along the same direction, we have
$$W=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\overrightarrow{F}.\overrightarrow{dx}=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Fdxcos0=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Fdx$$

According to Newton's second law of motion,
$$F=Ma$$
where a is  acceleration produced (in the direction of force) on applying the force.
Thus, we have
$$W=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Madx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}M\frac{dv}{dt}dx$$
or

$$W=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Mdv\frac{dx}{dt}$$
or
$$W=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Mvdv$$

when , 
at $x_1$, $V$=0  and at $x_2$, $V$=$v$. Here, $V$ is velocity.
Thus,
$$\tag{i}W=\int_{0}^{v}Mvdv=\frac{1}{2}Mv^2$$

If the body is at rest at $x_2$, and work is done against the force to displace it to $x_1$. Thus, total work done in moving the body form the point $x_2$ to $x_1$ is given by
$$W=\int_{x_2}^{x_1}\overrightarrow{F}.\overrightarrow{dx}$$
As force acts against the direction of displacement, we have
$$W=\int_{x_2}^{x_1}\overrightarrow{F}.\overrightarrow{dx}=\int_{x_2}^{x_1}\overrightarrow{F}dxcos180=\int_{x_2}^{x_1}-Fdx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Fdx$$
By solving as above we have
$$W=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Mvdv$$
At $x_1$, $V$=$v$ and at $x_2$, $V$=0. 
Thus, we have
$$\tag{ii}W=\int_{v}^{0}Mvdv=-\frac{1}{2}Mv^2$$
Here negative sign indicates work done against the force. If you add (i) and (ii), you will get total work done as *zero*. I hope it helped. **So, you are going wrong in integration.**